# How to debug random Outlook crashes (C# add-in)

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

From a lot of our customers, we have been getting complaints that Outlook unexpectedly crashes (complete process restart) when using our plugin.

So far it has been impossible to reproduce, we can only analyze the logs after the fact and the only thing we know so far is that if we turn one specific add-in off, then the problem stops (it's a local add-in that helps sending e-mails with a configurable template). This add-in runs on .NET and is written in C#.

We have spent weeks gathering and analyzing logs. The crash always reports an Event ID 1000 in the Event Log, which points the faulting module to kernelbase.dll / olmapi32.dll / wwlib.dll / ntll.dll.... or some other dll file. The crash happens on several Outlook builds, old or new, monthly channel or semi channel, doesn't matter.

From our code we were finally able to simulate one crash after running an analysis in VisualStudio which warned us about some potential NullExceptions, when testing with that we could simulate one Outlook crash pointing to Kernelbase.dll. We now fixed this in a new patch and still awaiting results from customers, but in the meantime are there any more options to debug such a random crash? Hope anyone can help us here.

Answer (score 1):

That is a widely spread problem when dealing with Office COM add-ins. The problem can be related to other add-ins, not only yours. Even to locate the source of the issue is very complicated in such cases. You can generate a dump crash and then analyze it to identify the source, but it may not help well because changes made by any add-in may not be detected following that way - the exception which could lead to the crash can be thrown by Outlook itself. For example, a badly written COM add-in may release a COM object and then finish its works, then at some point the host application detects that a required COM object is disposed and cannot continue execution, so it crashes suddenly.

To identify the source of the issue, first of all, you need to add any logging mechanisms to the add-in and see where and when the issue takes place. Then you can try to start simplifying the source code of your add-in by commenting line by line and seeing results after whether it helps or not. It also makes sense to try a newly created add-in, so it can be sure the issue comes from any other add-in, not your own code. There are a lot of helpful steps that could be made, but they depend on the specific scenario you deal with.

You can enable Outlook logs as well. Read more about that in the [How to enable global and advanced logging for Microsoft Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-enable-global-and-advanced-logging-for-microsoft-outlook-15c74560-2aaa-befd-c256-7c8823b1aefa) article.

Answer (score 0):

Try to collect a crash dump using ProcDump.exe and then open it in windbg.

Download ProcDump from
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump

and run the following from command line:

```
procdump.exe -e -ma -o -w outlook.exe
```